# Как в DataGridView отключить вставку новых строк?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, vb.net

Работаю с DataGridView программно, и вставку новых строк с клавиатуры нужно отключить.
При этом редактирование ячеек типа DataGridViewTextBoxColumn и DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn должно работать.

Можно ли это как то сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите значение false свойству [`DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)